# set hide toggle as default

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set hide a div as default when I use Toggle,
I did some research and couldn't find a good answer that fits my conditions.
As you can see by the following code, the `<p>` tag is showed by default, I want to hide it. I used `display:none;` but it didn't work.
Is there a way to just set the default on hide in the jQuery?

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
</p>
```

Comment: `display:none;` should work. Where and how did you apply it? For jQuery check `hide()`.

Comment: i used on the `<p>` tag, the `hide()` function hides something right? Why would i use that

Comment: Where is the problem ? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a1ksfqsg/)

Comment: @Azertit your question says *the <p> tag is showed by default, I want to hide it.* http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/ne34nah5/ - `display : none` works.

Comment: how can `display:none` not work?

Comment: @ShaunakD, yes as the default. the p tag is showed by default, I want to hide it as default.

Comment: @Azertit Please have a look to many anwsers/comments here, all are more or less accurate and giving you solution.

Comment: Toggle checks for it's visibility (display block or none) and toggles it, from one to the other. It doesn't matter if the element starts hidden or shown. http://jsfiddle.net/6dhv3fu2/

Comment: Might be you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413436/set-hide-toggle-as-default/29413576#29413576

Comment: the question is answered, i cant accept it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply style on `P` tag to `display:none` so it do not display on load time.

```
<p style="display:none">
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sb0xwxdj/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: none` for p. because script will override display property after clicking on button

```css
p{display: none;}
```

Comment: sure, you can add class on p also. There are many variant to create css rules

Answer (score 0):

In the document.ready have this:

```
$('p').hide();
```

This will hide the paragraph when the page loads and it will not be seen until the toggle button is clicked.